# How can I grow better shaped yellow squash?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, harvesting, squash

I am growing some early prolific straight neck yellow squash in my raised bed. I am getting a lot of flowers and squashes but they don't seem to be growing to full size. Am I doing something wrong?  See pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, this seems to have been due to excessive and abnormal heat we experienced for a few days.  I did not increase watering time and should have in hindsight.  Now that we are back to normal temperatures, he newer squash seems to have normal shape and size.

Comment: I wish I had.  I was not aware of this issue.  The other plant that was behind the one having the issues was less impacted because the shadow of this plant must be helping the soil stay moist instead of evaporating.

Comment: True and will try extra watering during hot temperature days